# Let $p$ be the largest prime less than or equal to $n$. Is $n$ $\underline{<}$ $p^2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Fix $n$ to be some positive integer greater than or equal to 2. Let $p$ be the largest prime less than or equal to $n$. Is $n$ $\underline{<}$ $p^2$?

Comment: Instead of using `\underline{<}`, you can use `\leq`.

Comment: Try using [Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there exists $n$ and $p$ such that $n>p^2, n>3$ and $p$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $n$. so we have: $p\leq p^2<n$.
 According to  Bertrand's postulate, there is always a prime number between $p$ and $2p$ and we have: $p^2>2p$ so there is a prime number between $p$ and $p^2$ as well. This contradicts the fact that $p$ was the greatest prime less than or equal to $n$ because we found a new prime between $p$ and $n$.
So our assumption was wrong and thus, $n\leq p^2$
As Joel said, now we should check the case for $n=3$ too. there we have: $2^2 = 4>3$

Comment: This just leaves out the one case with $n=3$.  There we have $2^2 = 4 > 3$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the note. i will add it now.

Comment: Fabulous!! Thank you. I was unaware of this postulate.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about Bertrand's postulate? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Chebyshev said it, but I'll say it again; There's always a prime between n and 2n. In particular, this means that for any $n>1$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $\sqrt{n}$.